# show uiview on top of everything (even keyboard)

Tags: iphone, keyboard, legacy

In my application, I sometimes show a message to the user and I want it to be on top of everything (even keyboard), like a UIAlertView could do.

I googled it and found the solution which is:

```
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:myViewOnTop];
```

This works. However this is not documented, so I guess Apple won't accept it, right ?

What do you think about it ? Do you know an Apple legacy way to do it ?

Thanks

Vincent

Comment: This should work perfectly and Apple should not complain ... it **is** documented. window is a subclass of UIView which has addSubview method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIWindow is just a subclass of UIView. Therefore the addSubView function is documented which should make it acceptable :)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. However, the fact that the delegate of UIApplication has a window (attribute window) is not documented (or I missed it). right ?

Comment: That's true but the UIApplication class does have an NSArray called windows. YOu can access the windows of the app using that :)

Answer (score 1):

`addSubView:` is documented and should not be a problem. However, you should ensure that you do not violate one of the gazillion clauses included in the Human Interface Guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Add your view directly to the keyWindow.